# Using same model for multiple resource in Laravel Filament

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

I have a Orders model and instead of showing Orders menu then letting user to use filters for Pending/Completed orders, i want to have two resources in sidebar (Pending Orders - Completed Orders)

How can i use same model for multiple resources like Laravel Nova?

I've created `PendingOrdersResource` / `CompletedOrdersResource` for that, added custom labels for each one. Then used `getEloquentQuery` to filter out each resource to its own states. I expected to have Pending Orders / Completed Orders on the sidebar with filtered state because of modified getEloquentQuery. However on the Filament sidebar now i have two Orders menu, and each ones URI is admin/orders.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to set a custom URL for the resource

```
protected static ?string $slug = 'pending-orders';
```

https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/admin/resources/getting-started#customizing-the-url-slug

Answer (score 3):

I separate everything in a resource file for this type of scenario. Something like the following.

```
protected static ?string $navigationGroup = 'Customers';
protected static ?string $label = 'Customer';
protected static ?string $navigationLabel = 'Customers';
public static ?string $slug = 'customers';
protected static ?int $navigationSort = 15;
```

Basically, here I separated the navigation group as Customers, Navigation label as Customer, Label as Customer, and slug (which will be place in url) as customers, and I also manually sorted the menu by navigationSort. this is the position of the menu.